# How do you update a MySQLi field using prepared statement if you are adding one to the field?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query here which adds +1 to existing field. However I do not know how I would do it using prepared statement. So here I am adding +1 to the existing number. I know how to do it all except the "+1" part.

```
$updateUsers = mysqli_query($MySQLi, "UPDATE `users` SET ArticlesWritten=ArticlesWritten +1 WHERE uUsername='{$_GET['uUsername']}'");
```

Comment: Never use $_GET directly in the sql. You are strongly recommened to escape it via `mysqli_escape_string` to prevent SQL attacks.

Comment: @user2433059, I have done that, this is an old query I showed you just the small part all of it is validated properly. Also why I am changing to prepared statements to help with the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE `table` SET `column`=`column`+1 WHERE `primary_key`=?";
$execute = $db->prepare($query);
if($execute) {
   $execute->bind_param('i', $primary_value);
   $execute->execute();
} else {
    echo 'We\'re having trouble connecting to the database at the moment, try again later!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sniko, seeing as this was not going to get me any answers.